# dayOfMonth(31) in Month.AUGUST

Tags: java, jodatime

Following code calculates the exact date when a child graduates from Kindergarden. Its always the 31th August after the 6th birthday. dob is the child´s birthday :

```
public static DateMidnight getKigaAustritt(DateMidnight dob){
    DateMidnight sechs = dob.plus(Period.years(6));
    DateMidnight austritt = new DateMidnight(sechs);
    if (sechs.getMonthOfYear() > Month.AUGUST){
        austritt = sechs.withYear(sechs.getYear()+1);
        austritt = sechs.withMonthOfYear(Month.AUGUST);
        austritt = sechs.withDayOfMonth(31);
    }else{
        austritt = sechs.withMonthOfYear(Month.AUGUST);
        austritt = sechs.withDayOfMonth(31);
    }
    return austritt;
}
```

Now, if i leave it at that, the method is called from elsewhere and i invariably get an error stating that dayOfMonth() has to be in the range [1,30]. If i change the code to ..withDayOfMonth(30) the program works fine, but graduates the child a day earlier. Now, MonthOfYear beeing August, i wonder why this is happening. Any hints?

Comment: Wenn schon, dann sollten die Variablen englische Namen haben!

Comment: Weil stackoverflow eine englischsprachige Site ist? Da gebe ich dir grundsätzlich Recht.

Comment: Im compilier alles sieht gleich. In the compiler it all looks the same.

Comment: And Java can even deal with Unicode :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the month for 'sechs' is not being set. This is because you are calling `sechs.withMonthOfYear` but assigning this to `austritt`. `withMonthOfYear` returns a modified copy, it does not modify the element on which it is called. Consider the following:

```
austritt = sechs.withYea(...)
                .withMonthOfYear(...)
                .withDayOfMonth(...);
```

Per [API](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateMidnight.html#withDayOfMonth%28int%29)

> Returns a copy of this date with the day of month field updated.
>
> DateMidnight is immutable, so there are no set methods. Instead, this method returns a new instance with the value of day of month changed.

Comment: Got it. I actually knew about DateMidnight beeing immutable, but i completely failed to see the refence here on my own. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `with*()` returns a new instance of date.

You need to do `sechs = sechs.with*()` or use the constructor instead.

Then return sechs.